# zsh's "echo SomeText >> **/filename" in other shells

Tags: shell, files, find, xargs, replace

I need to fill all files with a specific filename (recursively) with a text.
In zsh this can be done with

```
echo SomeText > **/TheFileName
```

I search generic solutions for sh-compatible and/or tcsh shells.
Is there a shorter/easier way than the following command?

```
find . -name "TheFileName" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -n -i -e '1c\nSomeText'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find . -name TheFileName -type f -exec sh -c 'for i do
     echo SomeText > "$i"; done' sh {} +
```

Comment: Would you mind explain me what the last `sh` is for? I don't understand why the first `sh -c` is not sufficient.

Comment: @mikeserv With `$1`, only the first listed file gets written to. Do you think it's only true for my shell (zsh) and my implementation of find (the GNU one)? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @mikeserv I confirm that my `find` doesn't go in the correct file's directory. And that would be strange because the point of the `+` is to launch the command only once with all the files as parameters. So, how could the command be in the right directory for each one?

Comment: So @StephaneChazelas, you meant either `for i do echo SomeText > "$i"; done` or `for i do echo SomeText > "$1"; shift; done`, right?

Comment: @lgeorget, yes, that was a typo, thanks for the edit. As mikeserv said, the second `sh` is for the inline-script's $0 (used for error messages for instance).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tee` for this:

If your shell properly matches the `**/TheFileName`, and the issue is simply getting the content in each file:

```
echo SomeText | tee **/TheFileName >/dev/null
```

If the issue is that `**/TheFileName` isn't matching properly, you can use `find`:

```
echo SomeText | find . -name TheFileName -exec tee {} + >/dev/null
```

If your `find` doesn't have `-exec +`, then the other solutions here are appropriate.

These also won't work if you have a very large number of files (greater than `getconf ARG_MAX`).

Comment: The limit on the number of concurrently open files is likely to be reached before that of ARG_MAX though.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit shorter:

```
find . -name TheFileName -type f -exec sed -n -i -e '1c SomeText' {} +
```